# When does sidekiq end a process, and thus release memory?

Tags: multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, memory-leaks, sidekiq

From the little I know of the inner workings of Ruby it only releases memory once the process if finished.

I'm debugging a very long running sidekiq Heroku process with memory issues and I'm trying to figure out the boundaries of a background process.

So... say I have sidekiq using 3 threads, and it's running 3 jobs at a time, and I have 100 jobs total. That mean its likely there will never be a break between jobs right? Does that mean memory won't be released until all 100 jobs are done? I'm assuming yes, it won't release until the 100 are finished.

But say I switch to 1 thread, and the 100 jobs run after each other. Will each job now be it's own process, or will sidekiq treat all those 100 queued jobs as a single process (even though it's only running one at a time)?

If so... is there a way to make each job it's own individual process which releases memory after it's done?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby uses garbage collection to reclaim memory.  It will release memory much quicker than you are thinking.  See also https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#memory-bloat

Comment: thanks! That's a really useful link actually. However, do you know the answer to the question.. in terms of a job being a process and if my assumptions are correct?

Comment: A job is not a process.  Sidekiq is a process which creates 25 worker threads (by default).  Each thread will execute a job in parallel, all in the same process.